# Calculo automático para registrarlo en base de dato cada cierto tiempo

Tags: php, mysql

acudo de nuevo en busca de ayuda para encontrar la forma de calcular un valor automáticamente y registrarlo en la base de datos cada cierto tiempo.

Necesito calcular cada 24 horas el valor de los intereses por un préstamo realizado  y actualizar y registrar en la bd todos los días el valor calculado.

Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

[image: Esta es la estructura de la tabla]

Realizare un SELECT que incluya las columnas fecha_solicitud y valor_prestamo y con esto contar los días transcurridos y con base en el valor aplicar el porcentaje de interés pero no se como hacer para que este se calcule automáticamente cada día y ademas realice el UPDATE en la bd.

La idea es tomar valor_prestamo y calcular el 0.03% cada día trascurrido desde la fecha_solicitud, ese calculo se realizaría a diario y se registrara en la bd ya que el usuario podrá consultar cual es el valor del interés a medida que transcurre el tiempo.

De antemano gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de la fórmula o algún ejemplo para ilustrarnos mejor lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Gracias por la edición. Sería bueno que respondieras en un comentario y me nombraras (poniendo el @ delante de mi nombre) para que me llegue una notificación cuando lo hagas.

Comment: Lo importante es, ¿no es mejor calcular esos intereses en el momento de mostrar los datos? ¿Necesitas que se haga el cálculo de manera masiva de forma cíclica? Aunque es innecesario se puede hacer. ¿Qué problema tienes para hacerlo? ¿Qué consultas SQL has probado?

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, lo tendré en cuenta.

Comment: Me acabas de dar una idea @OscarGarcia, no creo necesario registrar el valor del interés en la bd todos los días sino que lo calculo y lo muestro  y solo lo registro en la bd una vez se realice el pago del préstamo por parte del usuario. Gracias estaba bloqueado.

Comment: Probando a multiplicar por `0.0003` (calcular el `0.03%`) me he dado cuenta que es posible que tengas problemas si usas campos enteros en datos que pueden ser de coma flotante. En el ejemplo en línea de mi respuesta podrás ver que el campo `intereses` calculados aparece bien (`0.1056`), pero en el campo `valor_intereses` está mal porque se redondea a `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos soluciones:

### Actualizar los datos de manera periódica:

```
UPDATE pruebas SET valor_intereses = DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_solicitud) * 0.0003;
```

### Mostrar la información calculada:

```
SELECT
  *,
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_solicitud) dias,
  DATEDIFF(NOW(), fecha_solicitud) * 0.0003 intereses
FROM pruebas;
```

[Tienes un ejemplo en línea de ambos en este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ch24GsVAoVNZ5LBn1tmS35/0).

Comment: Y como podría hacer el UPDATE automaticamente transcurrido el tiempo? supongo que con JavaScript, pero esa es la parte que inicialmente me estaba partiendo la cabeza.

Comment: Podes crear un evento en mysql que se ejecute en el intervalo de tiempo que vos quieras, en el siguiente link hay un ejemplo https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/ donde crea un evento que hace inserts en tablas y elimina de otras y se ejecuta 1 vez por semana a partir de la fecha en que lo creo '2011-07-24 03:00:00'. Podes poner que se ejecute cada minutos, horas, dias, meses, años etc. Otra opcion es crear un archivo PHP que haga eso y dsp creas un .bat que lo ejecute y usando las tareas programadas de windows haces que ejecute ese .bat cuando quieras

Comment: Hola @Juan , creo que te has equivocado en el lugar donde publicar ese comentario. Lo has publicado en mi respuesta, no en la pregunta :)

Comment: Mil Gracias a los dos, @Juan, ambas respuestas complementan y dan solución a mi necesidad.